# View with model from action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

How can i pass view with model from filter in .Net Core? (i don't want redirect)

My action filter:

```
private class CustomFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly MainDbContext _mainDbContext;

    public CustomFilter(MainDbContext mainDbContext)
    {
        _mainDbContext = mainDbContext;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var model = _mainDbContext.Groups.ToList();
        context.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Index" };
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally if I do not want to redirect but want to manipulate or filter some data - I use a [web api](https://www.asp.net/web-api) controller instead. No redirect - just a an Ajax call

Comment: @MichaelHancock Above example action filter is only for simply show problem but my real action filter have more logics and is used on many actions and controllers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var model = _mainDbContext.Groups.ToList();

        var result = context.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result != null)
        {
            context.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Index", ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(result.ViewData)
            {
                Model = model
            }};
        }
    }
```

Also, consider using the [Result filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) instead of Action Filter.

> Result filters are only executed for successful results - when the action or action filters produce an action result. Result filters are not executed when exception filters handle an exception.

Comment: Agree, better use result filter. Thanks